# Evitar recargar pagina con envio de email (formulario)

Tags: php, javascript, email

Estoy terminando un simulador de inversión en donde el usuario elige el monto, se calcula el porcentaje según la cantidad de meses y después si lo desea, puede enviar esos datos por email.

El problema que tengo es que estoy tratando de usar el evento `event.preventDefault()` para evitar que la pagina se recargue.

**Ejemplo:**

```
document.getElementByName("add").addEventListener("click", 

function actualizarValor() {
  // codigo
  campo_resultado.value = suma_actual;

event.preventDefault()
});
```

y quitar esta linea: `echo "Gracias.<br>Un representante se pondr&aacute; en contato con usted. <a href=''>Cargar simulador</a>";` de PHP.

Uno de los errores que daba era que `document.getElementByName("add")` no estaba declarado y el formulario dejaba de funcionar. Perdón, pero no se como solucionarlo. Gracias!

Dejo el script completo

```js
function actualizarValor() {
  var campo_resultado = document.getElementById('txtValor');
  var valor = parseInt(document.getElementsByName('valorBase')[0].value);
  var suma_actual = valor;
  var radio = document.querySelector('input[name="mes"]:checked');
  if(radio) {
      var porcentaje = radio.value;
      suma_actual += valor * parseInt(porcentaje) / 100;
  }
  campo_resultado.value = suma_actual;
} //terminar y subir a github
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="col-md-6 p-5 rounded-lg shadow bg-gr">
<?php
if (!isset($_POST["add"])){
?>
<form action="" method="post">
<div class="form-group">
<div class="input-group mb-2">
<div class="input-group-prepend">
<div class="input-group-text">$</div>
</div>
<input type="text" name="valorBase" onkeyup="actualizarValor();" class="form-control" id="inputValor" placeholder="Ingres&aacute; tu inversi&oacute;n">
</div>
</div>


<div class="form-group">
<h5>Meses</h5>
<div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">

<label class="btn btn-secondary">
<input type="radio" name="mes" value="12" onclick="actualizarValor();" id="option1"> 3
</label>
<label class="btn btn-secondary">
<input type="radio" name="mes" value="16" onclick="actualizarValor();" id="option2"> 6
</label>
<label class="btn btn-secondary">
<input type="radio" name="mes" value="20" onclick="actualizarValor();" id="option3"> 12
</label>
<label class="btn btn-secondary">
<input type="radio" name="mes" value="24" onclick="actualizarValor();" id="option4"> 18
</label>
<label class="btn btn-secondary">
<input type="radio" name="mes" value="28" onclick="actualizarValor();" id="option5"> 24
</label>
</div>

</div>

<div class="form-group">
<div class="input-group mb-2">
<div class="input-group-prepend">
<div class="input-group-text">$</div>
</div>
<input type="text" name="total" readonly id="txtValor" value="" aria-describedby="addon-wrapping" class="form-control">
</div>
</div>

<hr>

<p>Envianos cuanto queres envertir!</p>

<div class="form-group">
<input type="email" name="from" class="form-control" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Email">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<input type="text" name="subject" class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre">
</div>

<input type="submit" name="add" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" value="Solicit&aacute; tu inversión">
<input type="reset" class="btn btn-light btn-sm" value="Reset">

</form>

<?php
} else {

if (isset($_POST["from"])){
    
 $from = $_POST["from"];
 $subject = $_POST["subject"];
 $message = 'Estoy interesado en invertir $'.$_POST["valorBase"].' al '.$_POST["mes"].'%. '. 'Total $'.$_POST["total"];
    
 mail("email@email.com", $subject, $message, "From: $from");
 echo "Gracias.<br>Un representante se pondr&aacute; en contato con usted. <a href=''>Cargar simulador</a>";
}
}
?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

¿Puedes probar con esto y decirme si funciona?

```
document.getElementByName("add").addEventListener("click",function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  // codigo
  campo_resultado.value = suma_actual;
});
```

Comment: Gracias Axel. Al final no lo van a usar y tuve que seguir con otro trabajos. De igual manera cuando termine lo retomo para que al menos quede bien.

Comment: @STN cuando lo retomes, no olvides comprobar qué solución te funcionó y compartirla con la comunidad o marcar como aceptada la respuesta que te sirvió. Un saludo.

Comment: Dale, gracias Álvaro!

Answer (score 1):

En tu formulario tiene tu  boton enviar

Puedes cambiar el type="button"

Comment: Gracias Franco. Como dije anteriormente, no lo van a usar y lo voy a seguir mas adelante.